# Consistent hashcode for an object in java

Tags: java, hashcode

In java Is it possible to get consistent hash code for an object when we are running the application multiple times

Comment: It depends upon the member variables of a class that are unique and used to calculate hashcode.

Answer (score 5):

Sure.  If it is a String for example, then `String.hashCode()` gives a consistent hashcode each time you run the application.

You only get into trouble if the hashcode incorporates something other than the values of the object's component fields; e.g. an identity hashcode.  And of course, this means that the object class needs to override `Object.hashcode()` at some point, because that method gives you an identity hashcode.

**FOLLOW UP**

Judging from comments on other answers, the OP still seems to be pursuing the illusory goal of a unique hash function; i.e. some function that will map (for example) any String to a hashcode that is unique for all possible Strings.

Unfortunately this is impossible in the general case, and in this case.  Furthermore, it is a simple matter to construct a *proof* that a `String` to `int` hash function that generates unique `int` values is *mathematically impossible*.  (I won't bore you with the details ... but the basis of the proof is that there are more `String` values than `int` values.)

In fact, the only situation where such a hash function is possible is when the set of all possible values of input type has a size that is no greater than the number of possible values of the integer type.  There are hash functions that will map a `byte`, `char`, `short` or `int` to a unique `int`, but a hash function that maps `long` values to unique `int` values is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on implementation on [hashCode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method of Object

It can also be

```
public int hashCode() {

    return 1;

  }
```

Comment: Returning a fixed value from `hashCode()` gives bad performance on collections using the hashcode. E.g. `HashMap`.

Comment: @michael.kebe Yes of course I just said it can be this also , just visualizing the scenario I didn't say to follow this :)

Answer (score 0):

No, not for objects in general. Objects with their own hashcode method will probably be consistent across runs.

Answer (score 0):

Implement/override the `public int hashCode()` method all objects have?

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide what makes the object the same.  Usually it is based on the content of one or more fields.  In this case, you should make the hashCode based on these fields. (And equals())

However, I would suggest you shouldn't rely on the hashCode being the same between runs of the application.  This is highly likely to break when you change code and very hard to fix when it does. e.g. if you add/remove a field which is part of the hashCode or change the way the hashCode is calculated or anything ti depends on, the hashCode will change.

What are you trying to do?  This sounds like a problem where a different solution would be better.

Comment: Hi..actually i m trying to generate unique hash code for string object like url string nd suppose my database is very huge.we know that two different objects can have same hash code..i want to know whether we  can create unique hash code for an object which will avoid the collision and will return the consistent  hash code on running  the application for multiple times.Is there any mechanism for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the [contract of hashCode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>     execution of a Java application, the
>     hashCode method must consistently
>     return the same integer, provided no
>     information used in equals comparisons
>     on the object is modified. **This
>     integer need not remain consistent
>     from one execution of an application
>     to another execution of the same
>     application.**
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
>     calling the hashCode method on each of
>     the two objects must produce the same
>     integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the
>     equals(java.lang.Object) method, then
>     calling the hashCode method on each of
>     the two objects must produce distinct
>     integer results. However, the
>     programmer should be aware that
>     producing distinct integer results for
>     unequal objects may improve the
>     performance of hashtables.

So it is not guaranteed that the hashCode is euqal between invocations. In reality, there are be quite some hashCode implementations that return the same value across invocations: `String` and all types used for boxing (like `Integer`) have a consistent return value for `hashCode`. Objects that only combine member hashCodes where each member has a consistent return value also feature this consistency. So, in practice it should be rather common to have a hashCode return value that is consistent accross invocations.

Comment: suppose i m having string for example  gmail.com.i want to know is it possible to generate unique hash code for this which will help me for improving the performance and another thing is,it should return me same hash code every time when i wil access it.Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Look at the code of java.lang.String: Its hashCode depends on all of its characters and nothing else, which means that two strings consisting of the same characters always have the same hashCode. So "gmail.com".hashCode() already returns a value throughout sepearate invocations.

Comment: millions of string objects are there..so as we know two different objects can also have same hash code.what can we do to avoid such collision.is there any solution for this?

Comment: hashCode is an int, ergo there are at most 2^32 hashCode values. But if you want to have a perfect hash function, consider reading the papers referenced in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_perfect_hashing